# ArgumentParser to call functions

Tags: python-3.x

I have 3 different functions that I want to call based upon the argument from the command line. I can't think of a simple way to make '-c' call function 1, '-o' call function 2, and '-p' call function 3.

Should I store the value using action? I only want one function to be called, which is why I believe the action argument to add_argument() will not work.

Comment: I guess I found a potential solution. I was using poor searches before I guess. My apologies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529610/call-function-based-on-argparse

Comment: If they're separate things, why not use a subcommand?

Comment: I guess there are several ways to do this. No solution seems simpler than directly using sys.argv instead of ArgumentParser() though.